# Sieve dimension of union of two sets.

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Let $P$ be a set of primes $\leq p$.  Let $A$ be a set of all integers $\leq x$ in which the elements in $A$ would avoid two classes mod $p_i$ for all $p_i \leq p$ (except $2$,$3$).  My understanding from my brief reading is that this corresponds to sifting dimension two. Suppose $B$ is another set with intergers $\leq x$ which avoids two classes mod $p_i$ for all $p_i\leq p$ (except $2$,$3$), and $A \cap B$ avoids $3$ classes mod $p_i\leq p$ (except $2$,$3$).  Can we estimate the set $A \cup B$?

Comment: Do you mean that $A$ is defined to be all integers up to $x$ other than those in the avoided residue classes? Or just that $A$ is some set that avoids those residue classes, but might be missing lots of other elements too?

Comment: yes. A is defined to be all integers up to x other than those in the avoid residue classes.  So it B.  A intersect B would have sifting dimension 3. I am interested in finding the smallest element in A U B.  My understanding is that the smallest element in A can be obtained via the sifting limit (of dimension 2), so is B.  Is it possible to obtain a better bound by looking at A U B.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The counting function of $A$ (the number of elements of $A$ less than $x$) will typically be a constant times $x/\log^2x$ (and sieves will provide an upper bound of this magnitude, though not always a lower bound). Similarly for $B$. So $A\cup B$ will have counting function that is some other constant times $x/\log^2x$. In fact it will be the sum of the other two counting functions (asymptotically), since the counting function of the intersection has magnitude $x/\log^3x$.

Maybe I'm not understanding your question well; but it seems like there's no natural way to study $A\cup B$ in this context other than studying $A$ and $B$ separately.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose it is possible that there is no answer to my question. I want to find the smallest member of A U B = min (smallest number in A, smallest number in B).  I was just hoping if there is any result which gets a better sifting limit of the set A.  However, I kind of guess that it may not be possible.

Comment: What if there is some extra information relating A and B. First of all, both A and B avoids 0 mod p. If A avoids t mod p, B avoids 2t mod p (for p>=5).

Comment: If they both avoid 0 mod $p$ for all $p$, won't that remove every single number except 1?

Comment: x is p^{r} where p is the largest prime that it would avoid. i want to find the smallest r in which it is non-empty.  For the set A, r is known to be bounded by <=4.26 (two dimenstional sieve).